# iMacros - How do I TAG URL with unique surrounding html?

Tags: macros, web-scraping, imacros

I need to extract "https://www.somesite.com/Some.Name.123" from the code below.

That code segment is repeated many times, and I need the URLs ..Some.Name.X.

There are other code segments between each of the ones I'm interested in, with very different surrounding html.   I don't need the ..Some.Name.x URLs in those other segments.

The following is unique to what URLs I need: `"<a class="-cx-PRIVATE-uiImageBlock__image"`

```
<div class="clearfix pvm">
<a class="-cx-PRIVATE-uiImageBlock__image -cx-PRIVATE-uiImageBlock__largeImage lfloat"
aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" href="https://www.somesite.com/Some.Name.123">
```

Comment: My code won't display.  I have <code> .. </code> around it. I also tried the code button.  Here's the code:
<code>
<td class="vTop hLeft"><div class="_e6"><div class="clearfix pvm"><a class="_8o _8t    lfloat" href="https://www.somesite.com/Some.Name" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
... (more html)
<div class="_6a _6b"><div class="fsl fwb fcb"><a href="https://www.somesite.com/Some.Name" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=1******1">Some Name</a></div>
</code>

Comment: You should read the formatting instructions...
Oh, and this is not data mining. It's web scraping. Data mining is advanced statistical analysis of data, not the collection.

Comment: I read the formatting instructions, and you can clearly see the <code> .. </code> I put in there, per the FAQ page.  I tried that after the code button failed.  It took that out of there now that it's highlighted as code (you left them in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to tag that preceding HTML with iMacros, or how to do that with jQuery as the structure will a bit different each time, but you could to this.

Save the web pages with iMacros.  Write a program (c, etc.) to read each of the saved files and write the URLs that follow "cx-PRIVATE-uiImageBlock__image" to a file.  Add that list of URLs to an iMacro, or have iMacros read the file, and then process each URL from iMacros.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some scripting. 
My answer makes use of jQuery

```
var listoflinks = []; //array containing your links
$('a[href*="somesite.com"]').each(function () { // for each link that contains somesite.com in href
    var j = $(this).attr('href'); //put the whole href in a variable
    listoflinks.push(j); // put all values in an array
});
```

you'll end up with an array that contains all the href values you're looking for.

If you want to see an example and/or you want to play around with the script you can go here:
[http://jsfiddle.net/flish/rESjg/](http://jsfiddle.net/flish/HMXDk/)

Edited 
Your code is still not clear enough, but hopefully this may help

```
<a class="sibling a" href="link">sibling a</a><br />
<div class="sibling div"><br />
    <a class="child a" href="start-with-link/correct-link">Child a</a><br />
</div><br />
```

Above is the markup I've used. What this means is that I have considered that you have the following elements:
a  // with a sibking div

div // with a child a

a // and all of them have appropriate classes

For this markup you can use the following code (jQuery, of course)

```
var listoflinks = []; //array containing your links
$('a[class="sibling a"]').siblings('div[class="sibling div"]').children('a[class="child a"]').each(function () {
    if ((($(this).attr("href")).substring(0,15))=="start-with-link"){
    var i = $(this).attr("href");
    listoflinks.push(i);
    }
    });
```

View detailed example at  http://jsfiddle.net/flish/HMXDk/

Be that as it may, you can add more sibling and children elements in case you have other html entities you forgot to mention

```
<a class="-cx-PRIVATE-uiImageBlock__image" ------------------ <div class="clearfix pvm"> <a class="-cx-PRIVATE-uiImageBlock__image -cx-PRIVATE-uiImageBlock__largeImage lfloat" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" href="somesite.com/some.name.123">
```

For example, what means ------------------ in your code above?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It looks like that will grab all the links that contain "somesitee.com," but I only want the links that are surrounded by the code I included (in the comment).   The other links (nneeded, and MANY) have different code around them.

Comment: what exactly is relevant in what you've posted? the css classes? which ones? the ids? which ones? you can do nested .each(function() and if and so on.

Comment: The URL in this code is better. (It's code left out in the middle above.)   This part of the code is unique to the URLs I need:
"<a class="-cx-PRIVATE-uiImageBlock__image"
------------------
<div class="clearfix pvm">
<a class="-cx-PRIVATE-uiImageBlock__image -cx-PRIVATE-uiImageBlock__largeImage lfloat" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" href="https://www.somesite.com/some.name.123">

Comment: Still not good enough code in my opinion. You need to provide a clear structure. I hope you did and I hope that now you have your answer.

Comment: I'm using the --------------- to separate the small code block (the unique part) from the code segment it is from.  That unique part is always before the specific URLs I want, and it not found elsewhere.  I don't see any other unique thing I could search on for the URLs I want.  (I can't use URL pattern matching - there are way to many that start the same way.)

Comment: To receive the correct answer you have to provide the WHOLE correct html. I cannot guess the structure. As you see my script makes use of the fact that some elements are on the same level (siblings) and others are nested inside them (children). Of course since you cannot post your real code here, you can try to do the same thing I did, having the advantage that you can say exactly how many siblings and / or children each element has.

Comment: I'm not sure what means a very complex example, I think it's rather simple. This thread is certainly not the place to talk. write me an email address in profile